# How to input fractions into WORD document using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to insert fractions into WORD using python-docx, like below result in picture. I can only insert these: 15/20 + 4/20. I want to have the style look like the picture shows. Is it possible to do it using python-docx, or other library in Python?

[image: fractions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python-docx doesn't implement a high-level API for working with Word formulas, but if you can construct the XML string yourself, you can insert it into a document. The XML Schema is Microsoft OMML, which is conceptually similar to MathML.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import parse_xml

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
omml_xml = '<p xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><m:oMathPara><m:oMath><m:f><m:num><m:r><m:t>1</m:t></m:r></m:num><m:den><m:r><m:t>2</m:t></m:r></m:den></m:f></m:oMath></m:oMathPara></p>'
omml_el = parse_xml(omml_xml)[0]
p._p.append(omml_el)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Here's that OMML fragment:

```
<p xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
  <m:oMathPara>
    <m:oMath>
      <m:f>
        <m:num>
          <m:r>
            <m:t>1</m:t>
          </m:r>
        </m:num>
        <m:den>
          <m:r>
            <m:t>2</m:t>
          </m:r>
        </m:den>
      </m:f>
    </m:oMath>
  </m:oMathPara>
</p>
```

That produces a Word doc with the fraction 1/2.

[image: Screenshot showing the fraction 1/2]

Comment: OMML doesn't seem well documented anywhere online, but a good article is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/mathml-and-ecma-math-omml

Comment: If you want to see more OMML syntax, on thing to try is creating a Word doc with an example formula, then open it with python-docx and check the XML with something like `document.paragraphs[0]._p.xml`

Comment: This works when adding a paragraph. But If I want to add it as a table's cell content, it will show the XML string:    row.cells[0].text =str(omml_el)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I needed to insert a formula into a cell of an existing spreadsheet table.
Thanks to this post I decided this way

```
from docx.oxml import parse_xml
import mathml2omml
import latex2mathml.converter


def test3():
    a = 5
    b = 2
  
    latex = r'''\frac{{{}}}{{{}}}'''.format(a, b)   
    mathml = latex2mathml.converter.convert(latex)  
    omml = mathml2omml.convert(mathml)              
    omml_xml = f'''
    <p xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"> 
    <m:oMathPara>{omml}</m:oMathPara>
    </p>
    '''                                            
    omml_el = parse_xml(omml_xml)[0]               


    document = Document('template_cell.docx')       
    table = document.tables[0]                     
    c = table.rows[0].cells                        
    p = c[0].paragraphs[0]                          
    p._element.append(omml_el[0])                  

    document.save('demo.docx')
```